# Keep running the container on ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, containers, amazon-ecs

This might be very beginner docker question.

```
FROM nvidia/cuda:11.0.3-base-ubuntu20.04

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip
RUN pip3 install torch torchvision

WORKDIR /work

COPY train.py /work/

ENV LIBRARY_PATH /usr/local/cuda/lib64/stubs
```

I built docker image from this `Dockerfile`.

Now I want to use this on `ECS`.

However, when deployment finished, this `container` stopped with `Essential container in task exited`.

I guess this is because no permanent　process(like server) is run on this `container`?

Come to think of it, when I deploy other containers on ECS it has `CMD` command and run some server such as `uwsgi`.

So, If I want to use this container on　`ECS`, I should run a server on this `container`?

Am I correct?

However what is the best practice for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want to run your Python model on your ECS.
Adding

```
CMD ["py","train.py"]
```

to your Dockerfile should be able to run your Python file on ECS.
However, I think you need to set up logic inside your script to make it run at different intervals or add a cron configuration if you want it to run at specific time.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I solved with `CMD /usr/bin/python3 -m http.server 8000 `